# Probability : In a class of 125 students 70 passed in Mathematics , 55 in Statistics and 30 in both. Then find the proabability...

Tags: probability

Probability : In a class of 125 students 70 passed in Mathematics , 55 in Statistics and 30 in both. Then find the probability that a student selected at random from the class has passed in only one subject .

My approach :

Let n(M) = 70 ( students passed in mathematics) ; n(S) = 55 ( students passed in Statistics) ; n(M $\cap S) = 30.$

Therefore, probability of students passed in mathematics = $\frac{70}{125}; $

Probability of students passed in statistics = = $\frac{55}{125}; $

Using $$P(M \cup S) = P(M) + P(S) - P(M \cap S)$$

$$\Rightarrow P(M \cup S) = \frac{70}{125} + \frac{55}{125} - \frac{30}{125} = \frac{19}{25}$$

But the answer is wrong ; book answer is : $\frac{13}{25}$

Please correct where I am wrong.. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

We need $$P(M\cap \bar S)+P(\bar M\cap  S)$$

Now, $$P(M\cap \bar S)=P(M\cap(U-S))=P(M)-P(M\cap S)$$

Answer (score 0):

Students who passed only in maths = 70-30=40
Students who passed only in statistics = 55-30=25
Probability that students passed in maths = 40/125
Probability that students passed in statistics = 25/125
So, the probability that student selected is passed only in one subject is (40/125 + 25/125)  = 65/125 = 13/25

Answer (score 0):

55 passed in statistics and 30 passed in both statistics and math, so 25 passed in statistics but not math.

70 passed in math and 30 passed in both statistics and math, so 40 passed in math but not statistics.

thus, 25 + 40 = 65 passed in one subject or the other (but not both).
$65/125 = 13/25$

Comment: Please improve your answer by formatting.See:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don't see what this adds to a 3 year old question...

Comment: Well I didn't see an answer there, and it's not relevant how old the question is. Not sure what your comment adds either...

Comment: Especially, when the question has an identical answer only 2 hours before you posted this.

Comment: Yeah I just saw the the one incomplete answer and didn't see the other, identical answer.